# Displaying full SQL array in textbox on Java

Tags: java, sql

```
void populateArray1() throws SQLException {

testConnection();
String vSQL = null;
Statement vStatement = null; 
ResultSet vResults = null;
boolean vFound= false; 

vSQL =  "SELECT contract_id, contract_start FROM contract ORDER BY contract_start";
vStatement =vConnection.createStatement() ; 
vResults = vStatement.executeQuery(vSQL);

vFound= vResults.next(); 

txtField1.setText("Contract ID: " + vResults.getString("contract_id") + ", Contract Start: " + vResults.getString("contract_start"));

}
```

Obviously this currently only brings back the first line of the array.

Comment: So I've realized text boxes can only handle 1 line. Anyone know what i should to next.

Comment: I understand that you wish to create a GUI application in java that will display the results of a SQL query. Do I understand correctly?

Comment: I'm guessing that you are using _Swing_. If so, then I suggest using a [JTable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) to display the [SQL] query results. Perhaps you should also revise [JDBC](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/TOC.html).